# Losing foreign key value in Django REST serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've simplified my code to make problem more clear.

I have two related models in my Django REST project. In my `models.py`:

```
class ClinicalResearch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Patient(models.Model):
    research = models.ForeignKey(ClinicalResearch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    observation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    desease = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    desease_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Then I create a serialiser:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('id', 'research_id', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name', 'location', 'birth_date', 'observation_date', 'desease', 'desease_date', 'gender')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # for tests only
        print(validated_data)
        return Patient(**validated_data)
```

View set:

```
class PatientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'research_id', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name', 'location', 'birth_date', 'observation_date', 'desease', 'desease_date', 'gender')
```

Router:

```
router.register(r'patients', ItemViewSet)
```

This implementation works fine for models without foreign keys. But when I post something like:

```
{
'id': null,
'research_id': 1,
'first_name': "john",
'second_name': "doe",
'middle_name', "",
'location': "Love Street",
'birth_date': "...",
'observation_date': "...",
'desease': "Lovefool",
'desease_date': "...",
"gender": "male to fem"
}
```

(the project with id=1 exists)

my ItemSerializer doesn't pass { research_id: 1 } to validated_fields.

The project_id field is *completely lost* during validation.

How to configure Serializer or ViewSet to make it workable?

Comment: What if you try just `project`: `fields = ('id', 'project', "data")`?

Comment: I tried it too. It doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? Provided example looks fine for me, I suppose it should work.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Edited to actual code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem related to `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` in this case Django expecting url for related object instead of id. Try to override type of serializer's field `research`:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    research = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('id', 'research', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name', 'location', 'birth_date', 'observation_date', 'desease', 'desease_date', 'gender')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # for tests only
        print(validated_data)
        return Patient(**validated_data)

    # If you need URLs for representation use this method
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """Set field type for output only"""
        self.fields['research'] = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField()
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, but after a small fix. You have to link the Primary key related field:

        research = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ClinicalResearch.objects.all())

Answer (score 0):

You have to link it:

accept
Looks like problem related to HyperlinkedModelSerializer in this case Django expecting url for related object instead of id. Try to override type of serializer's field research:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    research = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ClinicalResearch.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('id', 'research', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'middle_name', 'location', 'birth_date', 'observation_date', 'desease', 'desease_date', 'gender')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # for tests only
        print(validated_data)
        return Patient.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has bugged me many timen, yet never found a concrete solution. I am sharing my solution that has worked for me today. Hope it stays correct for long.

As a result, I get the following results as I wanted:

1. I wanted to pass a primary_key id for FK fields. I have three(3) in my model.
2. I wanted in my GET responses, all field values as defined. Not just id of FK. Hence the use of depth=1. (Which creates the issue in the first place)
3. I did not want to define two different serializers for GET and POST apis.

So this is how my serializer looks like:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(EnumSupportSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False, queryset=Address.objects.all()
    )

    slot = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False, queryset=SlotAvailablity.objects.all()
    )
    service = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False, queryset=Service.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = [
            "id",
            "title",
            "created_at",
            "patient",
            "address",
            "slot",
            "service",
            "status",
            "comment",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"status": {"required": False}}
        depth = 1

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """Set field type for output only"""
        self.fields["address"] = AddressSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
        self.fields["service"] = ServiceSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
        self.fields["slot"] = SlotAvailabilitySerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```